# How to push new json values to array in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, push

I have a code:

```
var name2 = <?php echo $json;?>;
```

I am working with data in *name2* and if user add some data to DB, I want to refresh data in name2. I use AJAX and getting data from server:

```
var json2 = $.parseJSON(data);
       EntriesCount =json2.length;
                 $(json2).each(function(i,val){
                     $.each(val,function(k,v){
                         console.log("I = " + i + " | " + k+" -> "+ v);
                        name2[i][k] = v;       
});
});
```

But, if a count of records in name2 less than in Server DB I have an "uncought type error (((((

So, I can fix it and how I can push the new entries in name2.

PS: The format of name2 is something like:

```
name2[i]['Name'], name2[i]['Phone'] and so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the missing item at "i" index. That is done by checking for its existence using typeof operator.

```
var json2 = $.parseJSON(data);
EntriesCount = json2.length;
$(json2).each(function (i, val) {
    $.each(val, function (k, v) {
        console.log("I = " + i + " | " + k + " -> " + v);
        if (typeof name2[i] == "undefined")
            name2[i] = {};
        name2[i][k] = v;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works for me! But can you deskribe it!? What did you do? What does it mean - {}     ?????????

Comment: @AntonRomanov {} is just an empty object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor